# i cannot get specific info in html by selenium

Tags: selenium

now i use regex some data get.
but i want to get data gracefully.. how can i do?

i want to get data

1. "/bookdb/review.nhn?bid=6253486"
2. 8.43
3. http://book.naver.com/search/search.nhn?query=%EB%A7%88%ED%81%AC+%EA%B3%A0%EC%9A%B8%EC%8A%A4%ED%86%A4&frameFilterType=1&frameFilterValue=619443
4. 타임비즈
5. 2010.03.20
6. 11,700
7. 13,000
8. -10%
9. ebook
10. 7,200
11. 8,000
12. -10%

this is html code

```
<div class="book_info">
        <h2><a class="N=a:bil.title,i:98000001_0000000000000000005F6BAE" href="/bookdb/book_detail.nhn?bid=6253486">뱀의 뇌에게 말을 걸지 마라&nbsp;<span>이제껏 밝혀지지 않았던 설득의 논리</span></a></h2>
        <div class="thumb type_end">
            <div class="thumb_type">
                <a href="javascript:showLayerBookImage();" class="N=a:bil.image,i:98000001_0000000000000000005F6BAE">
                        <img src="http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/062/534/06253486.jpg?type=m140&udate=20150715" alt="뱀의 뇌에게 말을 걸지 마라" onerror="emptyImg(this, 'm140')" >
                    <span class="mask"><span class="bg1"></span><span class="bg2"></span></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="book_info_inner">
            <div class="txt_desc">
                <a id="txt_desc_point" href="/bookdb/review.nhn?bid=6253486" class="N=a:bil.point,i:98000001_0000000000000000005F6BAE">
                    <div class="review_point2"><span style="width:84.3%;">별점</span></div>
                    <strong>8.43<span class="blind">점</span></strong> <span class="bar">|</span> 네티즌리뷰 <strong> 152</strong><span class="cnt">건</span></a><a id="reviewWriteTopBtn" href="#" class="review_write N=a:bil.reviewwrite">리뷰쓰기<em></em></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <em>저자</em> <a href="http://book.naver.com/search/search.nhn?query=%EB%A7%88%ED%81%AC+%EA%B3%A0%EC%9A%B8%EC%8A%A4%ED%86%A4&frameFilterType=1&frameFilterValue=619443" class="N=a:bil.author,i:619443">마크 고울스톤</a><span class="bar">|</span><em>역자</em> <a href="http://book.naver.com/search/search.nhn?query=%ED%99%A9%ED%98%9C%EC%88%99&frameFilterType=1&frameFilterValue=18894" class="N=a:bil.translator,i:18894">황혜숙</a><span class="bar">|</span><a href="http://book.naver.com/search/search.nhn?filterType=7&query=%ED%83%80%EC%9E%84%EB%B9%84%EC%A6%88" class="N=a:bil.publisher">타임비즈</a>
                    <span class="bar">|</span>2010.03.20</div>

                <div class="tit_ori"><em>원제</em> Just listen</div><div>
                <em>페이지</em> 320<span class="bar">|</span><em>ISBN <a id="isbnBtn" href="#" onclick="clickcr(this,'bil.isbn','','',event);"><img src="http://static.naver.net/book/img3/btn_question.gif" width="14" height="14" alt="ISBN 안내 레이어 보기" title="ISBN 안내 레이어 보기"></a></em> 9788963894966<span class="bar">|</span><em>판형</em> A5, 148*210mm<span class="bar">|</span><span class="box_more"><a href="#" class="more" title="책정보 더보기" id="btnMoreBookInfo" onclick="showLayerMoreBookInfo(); return false; "><span class="blind">책정보</span>더보기</a><!-- [D] 더보기 레이어 오픈시 클래스 "on" 추가 -->
                <span class="ly_more">
                <em>도서관 소장 정보</em>
                <a href="http://www.dibrary.net/search/common/makeDetailUrl.jsp?control_no=KMO201007694" target="_blank" class="N=a:bil.nl">국립중앙도서관</a>
                </span>
                </span>
                </div>

                <div class="price_area">

                <div class="lowest">
                                <em>도서</em>
                                <strong>11,700<span class="won">원</span></strong>
                                <span class="price">13,000<span class="won">원</span></span>
                                <span class="discount">-10%</span>
                            </div>
                        <div class="ebook">
                            <em>ebook</em>
                            <strong>7,200<span class="won">원</span></strong>
                            <span class="price">8,000<span class="won">원</span></span>
                                <span class="discount">-10%</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <div class="btn_inner">
                    <form id="zzimForm" action="#" method="post"></form>
                        <a href="/bookdb/price.nhn?bid=6253486" class="btn_price_comp N=a:bil.price">가격정보</a>
                    <a href="#" id="deleteZzimBtn" onclick="" class="btn_wishlist del" title="찜삭제하기">찜삭제하기</a><div class="u_likeit_module">
                        <div href="#" class="u_likeit_btn">
                            <a href="#" class="u_btn"><span class="u_ico"></span><em class="u_cnt"></em></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function(oData) {
                            window.__oLikeItData = oData;
                            var s = document.createElement("script");
                            s.type = "text/javascript";
                            s.charset = "utf-8";
                            s.src = oData.domain + "/static/js/likeIt.v2.desktop.init.js?v="+ (new Date()).toDateString().replace(/\s/g,"");
                            (document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).appendChild(s);
                        })({
                            serviceId : "BOOK"
                            , contentId : 6253486
                            , domain : "http://common.like.naver.com"
                            , lang : "ko"
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div id='spiLayer1' class='wrap_social naver-splugin'
                     data-style='type_c'
                     data-oninitialize="splugin_oninitialize();"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="isbnHelpBox" class="help_box" style="display:none;">
                <p><em>ISBN</em>이란?</p>
                <span>국제표준도서번호(International Standard Book Number)로서, 국제적으로 표준화된<br>방법에 따라 전세계에서 생산되는 도서에<br>부여된 고유번호를 말합니다.</span>
                <a id="isbnHelpBoxCloseBtn" href="#"><img src="http://static.naver.net/book/img3/btn_close4.gif" width="20" height="19" alt="닫기" title="닫기"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my code sample

```
mydriver.get(link_tmp)
element = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='book_info_inner']")
text_data = element.text.replace('\n', '')
is_ebook = text_data.find("ebook") > -1
# pattern = ".*|ISBN 9(.*)|.*"
pattern = ".*ISBN (.[0-9]+).*"
compile_pattern = re.compile(pattern)
isbn = compile_pattern.findall(text_data)
```

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `get_attribute` method. For the first value it works like follow:

```
element = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="txt_desc_point"]')
href_value = element.get_attribute('href')
```

This should return required `"/bookdb/review.nhn?bid=6253486"`

If you want just to get text from element (like value 6):

```
element = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="lowest"]/strong')
value = element.text
```

You should get `11,700`

Comment: try `mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(//a[@id="txt_desc_point"]/strong).text`

Comment: If my answer solve your problem, please accept it or make upvote if it was useful. thanks

Comment: i can't get 9788963894966

Comment: How much elements you get if to use `mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath(//a/em[span[@class="bar"]])` ?